# Open_Basdir Restriction in effect File(/foo/bar) is not within the allowed paths (.../foo/bar)

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I am running PHP 5.2.6 with open_basedir set. Now I get the following message of a path not being in the the list of allowed dirs, but it is in the list:

```
"is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. 
   File(/srv/www/www.example.com/httpdocs/pdf_files) is not within
   the allowed path(s):    
   (/srv/www/services.example.com:/tmp:/srv/www/www.example.com/httpdocs/pdf_files:/usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/)"
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the path did not exist.